# Fill the area between \draw lines and arc

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am trying to fill the area between the lines and arc in latex. Below is the code I have used and it's not filling up the whole area. I am sure there is somewhere I am not getting it right, I am new to this platform. Can someone help? Here are my code and the output
[image: Filled area after running the code]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[name path=A](0.4,0)--(0.2,0)--(0.2,-0.3)--(0.8,-0.5)  (-0.8,-0.5)-- (-0.2,-0.3)--(-0.2,0)--(-0.4,0);
\draw[name path=B](0.8,-0.5)--(0.3,-2)(-0.3,-2)--(-0.8,-0.5)-- (0.8,-0.5);
\draw[name path=C](0.6,-2)++(180:0.3) arc (0:-180:0.3);
%\draw[name path=D](-0.8,-0.5)--(0.8,-0.5);
\begin{pgfonlayer}{bg}
\fill [orange!90,
intersection segments={
    of=A and B,
    sequence={L2--R2}
}];
\fill [orange!90,
intersection segments={
    of=B and C,
    sequence={L2--R2}
}];
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the desired result is

[image]

you can use:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw
  (0.4,0)--(0.2,0)--(0.2,-0.3)--(0.8,-0.5)
  (-0.8,-0.5)-- (-0.2,-0.3)--(-0.2,0)--(-0.4,0)
;
\draw[fill=orange!90]
  (0.8,-0.5)--(0.3,-2)
  arc (0:-180:0.3)
  --(-0.8,-0.5)--cycle
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

A [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) alternative, with a bit of fiddling to make the curve at the bottom look neat by finding the tangent points.  You can (I believe) do something similar in tikz using the `tangent` coordinate system.
[image: a diagram with a vessel, almost full of orange fluid]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    % set the various points
    z4 = 190 up rotated 25;
    z3 = 200 up rotated 5;
    z2 = z3 shifted 30 up;
    z1 = z2 shifted 20 left;

    % now find the tangent point
    path c, c'; 
    c = fullcircle scaled 50 rotated 90;
    c' = fullcircle scaled abs(z4) shifted 0.5 z4;
    (t,t') = c intersectiontimes c';
    path side, vessel;
    side = z1--z2--z3--z4--subpath(t,4) of c;
    vessel = side & reverse side reflectedabout(up,down);

    level = 3.1;
    fill subpath(0+level,length(vessel)-level) of vessel 
         -- cycle withcolor 1/2[red + 1/2 green, 15/16 white];
    draw vessel withpen pencircle scaled 1;

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Compile with `lualatex` (or strip off the LaTeX wrappers and use `mpost`)